# How do I move save data from the hard disk to the cloud?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, xbox-one

In the past I have saved games to the hard disk, but now that the Xbox has the option to save game data to a cloud based service I am considering using this instead, as I would like to ensure that in the event anything happens to my Xbox that I will still have the save games for the games that I play.

I have searched online for information on how to set this up but haven't found any information so I was hoping that somebody here would know;

Is it possible and if so how? How would I export save data from the hard disk to the cloud, so I can start using the cloud as my primary save point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to [enable cloud saves](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/game-saves-in-the-cloud/cloud-save-games):

> 1. From the Xbox Dashboard, go to Settings, and then select System.
> 2. Select Storage, and then select Cloud Saved Games.
> 3. Select Enable Cloud Saved Games.

Once you do this, you will be prompted on startup for most games which save device to use, in the same way you would be prompted if you had external storage plugged into your box.

Then you need to move save games (if they already exist)

> 1. Sign into your Xbox LIVE profile.
> 2. Go to Settings, and then select System.
> 3. Select Storage.
> 4. Select the storage device that contains the saved game that you want to move to the cloud.
> 5. Select Games.
> 6. Select the game with your saved game.
> 7. Select your saved game.
> 8. Select Move.
> 9. Select Cloud Saved Games.

Keep in mind that space is limited to 512 MB (but in my experience that has never been an issue).  I use this capability a lot to go between consoles - it is convenient.